# Instant detection of digital or analogue variation of a variable with Mathematica in Windows 8.1

Tags: interoperability, java, .netlink, input-devices

I am using an assembly that contains two acquisition board (PCI-1742U-AE and PCIE-1816H-AE) and an external circuit, connected to boards. The computer uses Windows 8.1, and the communication is done with Wolfram Mathematica 11, (through DLL libraries associated to these acquisition boards). Asynchronously, at any unscheduled time, a variation of an analogue or digital signal occurs, which signals the fulfillment of some conditions. How can I use the event occurred, even when it appeared, to trigger a desired soft routine? Mathematica can work with Java or .Net Framework. I think this is similar to the software IRQ, but I don't know how to manipulate, or if this is possible.It is possible to capture a hardware IRQ within Mathematica?